# Defining a sequence with contstraints

Tags: calculus

Good morning,

I have difficulties to solve the following problem. I need to find a decreasing sequence, say $(c_t)_t$ (the starting point of the sequence is not important), such that:

1) $\lim_{t}c_t=0$;

2) $c_t - c_{t+1}\geq \frac{1}{log(t+1)t}$ for all $t$.

Does such a sequence exists? If so, is it possible to provide an example?

Thanks in advance,

Umberto

Comment: Perhaps try to find an equivalent function, i.e. an $f(x)$ that behaves in a similar way; if $c_t - c_{t+1}\geq \frac{1}{log(t+1)t}$ then $\frac{1}{log(t+1)t}$ may be the derivative of $f(x)$; try integrating and go from there.

Comment: Thanks Gil for your quick reply; however I don't think how it could work out since the constraint is expressed in terms of differences and not of $c_t$ only. Maybe it could work out in case the inequality were of the tyoe " $\leq$ ". But maybe I did not catch what you are saying.

Comment: Say you take a much simpler function, like $f(x) = x^2$ as a function. Draw a table with columns for number of terms, value of f(x), values of the first difference (difference between terms of f(x)), and value of the second difference (difference between terms of the first difference). I think you will find that the values of the first difference are equivalent to $f'(x) = 2x$ and the values of the second as equivalent to $f''(x) = 2$. Therefore if you know the function of the first difference already ($\frac{1}{log(t+1)t}$) then you can integrate to find the original function.